# Model ratio in a one-way repeated measures ANOVA in R?

Tags: r, regression, anova, manova

I've got a dataset with two measures in a group of people, before (pre) and after (post) an intervention. Second measure is always greater than first one.

My assumption is that the initial value determines the magnitude of the post-intervention measure, so, the lower the initial value, the higher the increase, the higher the initial value, the lower the increase.

The target of my analysis is not the change itself, but the ratio post/pre intervention. My main outcome should be a pvalue of the change (it it is significant or not) and a graph pre Vs predicted(post/pre).

I’ve tried a one-way repeated measures anova, but this way I only analyse the variance, I cant predict the outcome.

```
library(car)
options(contrasts=c("contr.sum","contr.poly"))
measure1<-runif(1000,0,1000)
measure2<-measure1*(200-20*log(measure1))
lmmodel <- lm(cbind(measure1,measure2) ~ 1)
measureFactor<-factor(c("measure1","measure2"), ordered=F)
finalmodel<-Anova(lmmodel,idata=data.frame(measureFactor),idesign=~ measureFactor,type=3)
summary(finalmodel)
```

I have the impression that this is way more easy than I think, but I’m blocked, any clues?

SECOND: what if there are two groups, the first one is a “control” group and the other one is an “intervention” group, both with measures pre and post intervention, how would this modify my model? How could I get the pvalue of differences between the two groups.